# problema con inserción en dos tablas simultáneamente - php - SQL

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, insert

tengo problemas al insertar en dos tablas diferente, la cosa es que están relacionadas entre si, el primer insert lo realiza perfectamente, luego selecciono el identificador que le asigno y intento realizar el segundo insert pero ese no lo ejecuta

```
public function registrarDatos($num,$peso,$Estatura,$IMC,$Pecho,$Bicep,$Muslo,$cintura,$pgpecho,$pgbrazo,$pgcintura,$RE,$usu,$fecha,$obs,$proxE){
    $this->conexion();
    $vowels = array("/");
    $resultado = str_replace($vowels,"-","$proxE"); 
    $fecha2 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time());     
    $n=0;
    $sql = "insert into datos values(NULL,$num,$peso,$Estatura,$IMC,$Pecho,$Bicep,$Muslo,$cintura,$pgpecho,$pgbrazo,$pgcintura,$RE,'$usu','$fecha','$obs','$resultado',1)";     
    $sentencia = $this->m->query($sql);     
    if($this->m->affected_rows > 0){    

        $sql = "select id_dat from datos order by id_dat desc limit 1";
        $sentencia = $this->m->query($sql);
        while($rs = $sentencia->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
            $n=$rs[0];
        }

            $sql2 = "insert into historial values(NULL,$n,NULL,NULL,$num,'$fecha2')"; 
            //insert into historial values(NULL,128,NULL,NULL,12,'2017-12-06 13:01:11') 
            $sentencia2 = $this->m->query($sql2);   
            echo "<script>alert('insert into historial values(NULL,$n,NULL,NULL,$num,$fecha2)');</script>";                                         
            if($this->m->affected_rows>0){
                echo "<script>alert('Se puedo Registar en tabla Historial');</script>";
            }else{
                echo "<script>alert('No se puedo Registar en tabla Historial - insert into historial values(NULL,$n,NULL,NULL,$num,'$fecha2')');</script>";
            }



    }else{
        echo "No se pudo registrar, intente nuevamente";
        $this->desconexion();
    }

}
```

hago que me muestre o el segundo insert para ver que es lo que me esta mandando al sql, lo copio, ejecuto manualmente en el sql y lo inserta, entonce no se que error tengo, Ojala me puedan ayudar.

Comment: tu fecha esta con guiones en cuano a las horas y minutos, en vez de 2 puntos

Comment: lo cambien, pero aun asi no lo ejecuta

Comment: que quiere decir no ejecuta? que tipo de error da?

Comment: que no me debe estar ejecutando la sentencia, porque no hay registros en la tabla, ni siquiera entra al if o el else